# Spring-WS validate Signature and extract SOAP-Header in Endpoint

Tags: java, web-services, soap, spring-ws

we have a webservice that gets the next SOAP message. I'm posting only the header that it's the important part for our problem.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
  <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-65E18DC0CA7D9A38B214168992655731">THE_CERTIFICATE</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
  <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="SIG-65E18DC0CA7D9A38B214168992656685">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
        <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="SOAP-ENV"/>
      </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
      <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
      <ds:Reference URI="#id-65E18DC0CA7D9A38B214168992656044">
        <ds:Transforms>
          <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
            <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList=""/>
          </ds:Transform>
        </ds:Transforms>
        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
        <ds:DigestValue>DIGEST_VALUE</ds:DigestValue>
      </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue>THE_SIGNATURE</ds:SignatureValue>
    <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-65E18DC0CA7D9A38B214168992655892">
      <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-65E18DC0CA7D9A38B214168992655893">
        <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-65E18DC0CA7D9A38B214168992655731" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
      </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
  </ds:Signature>
</wsse:Security>
```

The certificate used to sign the petition is validated by Spring with the next configuration (server side):

```
<sws:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor">
        <property name="validationActions" value="Signature" />
        <property name="validationSignatureCrypto">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.support.CryptoFactoryBean">
                <property name="keyStorePassword" value="passtrustore" />
                <property name="keyStoreLocation" value="classpath:/ts-webservice.jks" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="securementActions" value="Signature" />
        <property name="securementUsername" value="user" />
        <property name="securementPassword" value="pass" />
        <property name="securementSignatureKeyIdentifier" value="DirectReference" />
        <property name="securementSignatureCrypto">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.support.CryptoFactoryBean">
                <property name="keyStorePassword" value="passkeystore" />
                <property name="keyStoreLocation" value="classpath:/ks-webservice.jks" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</sws:interceptors>
```

Everything works fine, but we are trying to extract the binarySecurityToken in the endpoint, because we use that certificate to get the ID of the signer and return in the response some personal information. We could add it again as an input parameter for this method, but we don't want to send the same certificate twice if we already have it in the header.

The method that returns the request is the next onee:

```
@PayloadRoot(localPart = "ValidateUserRequest", namespace = GET_TARGET_NAMESPACE)
public @ResponsePayload
ValidateUserResponse validateUser(@RequestPayload ValidateUserRequest request, MessageContext messageContext) throws WSSecurityException,
        CertificateException {
    // read SOAP Header
    SoapMessage mc = (SoapMessage) messageContext.getRequest();
    String soapNamespace = WSSecurityUtil.getSOAPNamespace(mc.getDocument().getDocumentElement());
    Element elem = WSSecurityUtil.getDirectChildElement(mc.getDocument().getDocumentElement(), WSConstants.ELEM_HEADER, soapNamespace);

    // get the BinarySignature tag
    // FIRST getFirstChild() is NULL if we have validated the request
    Node binarySignatureTag = elem.getFirstChild().getFirstChild();
    BinarySecurity token = new X509Security((Element) binarySignatureTag);

    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(token.getToken());
    CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(in);

    // do stuff with the certificate and return values
}
```

When Spring validates the signature of the request, it seems that the headers are removed, so we cannot access to the first child of the header element. If we comment the validation part in our application-context, the previous code works like a charm and we get the certificate.

How can we avoid this behavior? Why is the header from the request being removed after the validation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After a long night researching and reading Spring documentation, I found a workaround. I don't understand why Spring is consuming the headers, or why my endpoint isn't receiving the headers, however we could extract the certificate with the next code (with signature validation activated):

```
@PayloadRoot(localPart = "ValidateUserRequest", namespace = GET_TARGET_NAMESPACE)
public @ResponsePayload ValidateUserResponse validateUser(@RequestPayload ValidateUserRequest request, MessageContext messageContext) throws WSSecurityException, CertificateException {
    List<WSHandlerResult> handlerResults = (List<WSHandlerResult>) messageContext.getProperty(WSHandlerConstants.RECV_RESULTS);
    WSHandlerResult rResult = handlerResults.get(0);
    List<WSSecurityEngineResult> results = rResult.getResults();

    WSSecurityEngineResult actionResult = WSSecurityUtil.fetchActionResult(results, WSConstants.SIGN);

    X509Certificate returnCert = null;
    if (actionResult != null) {
        returnCert = (X509Certificate) actionResult.get(WSSecurityEngineResult.TAG_X509_CERTIFICATE);
    }
// do stuff with the certificate and return values
}
```

After some researching I found that Spring is saving in the MessageContext the results processed in the validation, which contains the certificate (see `Wss4jSecurityInterceptor#updateContextWithResults`).

Comment: Wouldnt be better to use AOP to validate upon the `messageContext` param?